# Distributing a cocoa touch dynamic framework written in swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3, realm

Hi i am facing issue while distributing a cocoa touch dynamic framework written in swift its working fine in when i m using in my company apps but when i send it to other company developer its crashes without giving any crash log at run time.I am creating sdk from workspace with alamofire and Realm as dependencies added via cocoapods. The framework is added as embedded binary in the projects.Since i dont get any logs i m unable to find the issue.I am following guidelines provided by apple while distributing.Any one faces this issue .Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Whare is Realm.framework and Alamofire.framework located? Build to single framework all together? Or your framework contains both frameworks?

Comment: Hi these are located in the workspace of my  custom framework.

Comment: Can you make sure the dependencies were copied to the app?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi yes they were copied to app